# AngularJS continue loop from index

Tags: angularjs

would like to get this angularjs loop to work.

It works now, but I need to add more or start at a slice index, actually continue the loop were it ended...

```
**html code:**
<div ng-repeat="company in companies" class="swiper-slide">


**angular:**
$scope.setCompanies = function (data, from, to) {
    $scope.companies = data.slice(from, to);        
}
```

now this works as it should. But when I load more companies from data and slice it, the loop starts from 0. I need to continue the loop were it stopped. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: how ngRepeat ended in a loop?

Comment: only store the "from" information, and adds to $index, if you need to display this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter that slices the array from an specified index, and use this filter on ng-repeat loop.

```
YOUR_APP.filter('sliceItems', function() {
    return function(input, startFrom) {
       return input.slice(startFrom);
    };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqr1zoghpvZnl4jQbki6?p=preview) (filter values from view)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/egh3puqid8W7btnvgElk?p=preview) (filter values from controller)

Comment: Thanks! But I call that function for another place in code. How can I acheive this? The $scope.setCompanies updates the repeat each time I reach a specific index within the array...

Comment: You can use `$filter('sliceItems')(YOUR_ITEMS,  NUMBER_TO_SLICE);`. I added a plunker to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used push instead to fill the array updating the items in companies. I do not know if this is the right way, probably not, but its good enough for now. Thanks all!